# What's the difference between "last week's meeting" and "the last week's meeting"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, definite-article

Is there any difference between "last week's meeting" and "the last week's meeting"?
For example, do "I didn't attend last week's meeting" and "I didn't attend the last week's meeting" differ in terms of naturalness, meaning and context?

Answer (score 1):

> **Last week's meeting**
>
> A meeting that happened in the week before the week you are in now

> **The last week's meeting**
>
> A meeting that happened in the week before a week in the past

Suppose regular weekly meetings are scheduled for Wednesdays. Today is Monday October 18 2021, so **last week's meeting** happened on Wednesday October 13 2021

If we are talking about (for example) 25 August 2021, if I say I had missed **the last week's meeting**, I mean I missed the meeting that happened on Wednesday 18 August 2021.